# How to make python response after a certain amount of time?

Tags: python

I want to make python respond to an answer after 10 seconds.

I am doing the Python Challenge and I have to write a program that asks the user '"What is your question?". The program should response with "Let me think about that" and pause for 10 seconds before responding with "I don't want to answer that question right now".

The program should then ask the user the same question that the user entered and then look at their response.

This is what I have so far:

```
import time
timeout=time.time()+60*10
while True:
    answer=str(input('What is your question?'))
    print('Let me think about that')
```

I don't really know what `timeout=time.time()+60*10` or `while True` means but when I searched the internet, it seems to be the right one. All I can get Python to do now is ask the question and wait for input and ask the question again without waiting.

Another problem is I put str before input which I think it means you can only give letters, not number. But when I use number as an input, Python still accept it as a string.

Comment: _I don't really know what 'timeout=time.time()+60*10' or 'while True' means_ You should **:-)** (I'm not trying to be mean or anything... I truly think it's the best way of learning)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `time.sleep` to pause a python program for n seconds:

> ```
> Help on built-in function sleep in module time:
> ```
>
> sleep(...)
>       sleep(seconds)
>
> ```
> Delay execution for a given number of seconds.  The argument may be
> a floating point number for subsecond precision.
> ```

so to pause for 10 seconds, just add `time.sleep(10)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want your program to wait for ten seconds, use time.sleep(10).  It will simply make the program pause for ten (or however many) seconds, then resume and execute the remainder of its code.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.sleep